# Upgrading Django from 1.4 to 1.5 -- url tag changed?

Tags: django

I upgraded my django project from 1.4 to 1.5 and now I'm getting the error that my `url` tags are formatted incorrectly. I did some research to find that, I believe, *all* my `url` tags are now in the wrong format.

In 1.4, my `url` tags looked like this: `{% url path.to.view %}`
In 1.5 the `url` tag must look like this: `{% url 'path.to.view' %}` (note the single quotes)

Am I reading this correctly? All `url` tags need single quotes around the path to the view? Isn't that a huge inconvenience since people upgrading will have to change *every* single `url` in their templates to add single quotes? Is there a quicker way to deal with this? I have a *lot* of templates (it's a large corporate web application).

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to deal with it. If you were to go through the pain, I would recommend you consider 1.6 (latest stable release), as there are more significant changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are reading it correctly. The change is covered in the [release notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#django-1-5-release-notes)

The change might be inconvenient, but it makes the url tag consistent with others, and allows you to use variables as well as strings as tag arguments. There was an option to use the new style tag in Django 1.3 and 1.4 to allow users to prepare for the change.

Comment: Brutal, alright thanks. I guess a day of updating templates is ahead of me.